# Canonical way to exclude field that might not exist or have empty string from ElasticSearch result

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have an index that some documents don't have `legacyAccountId` or even that field exists it contains empty string `""`.

I want to filter out those ones in my search result, my current approach is:

```
query = s.query(Q('bool',
                  should=should_matches,
                  # Result must have legacyAccountId values
                  must=[Exists(field='legacyAccountId')],
                  must_not=[Term(legacyAccountId='')])
                )
```

Is there a better/canonical way to do it?

Comment: That's the correct approach if you want the field to exist and have a non-empty value.

Comment: I see, thanks, thought I was doing something dumb and there is a more elegant way to deal with this problem.